# Confusing about the unit of Fermi velocity

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, units, unit-conversion

The unit 'eVA(angstrom)' is used in some ARPES papers for the Fermi velocity. How can I convert it to the conventional unit ‘m/s’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the Fermi velocity alone but the product $$ \hbar v_F $$
Which has dimensions of energy times lengths. 
If you want the velocity in m/s first divide by $ \hbar $ (you can find the value in $ eV \cdot s $) and get the velocity in Angstrom/s and then convert the Angstroms to meters.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is:

$1 \ \text{eVA}$ = $1.519 × 10^5 \text{m/s}$